# while parsing data in json getting error java.lang.nullpointerexception & end of input character at 0

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

this is my service code. please help me to get rid from` this. i call this service on button click . but getting this error every time.thanks in advance. also check the link to webservices don't know is it correct or not

```
package com.ballerxtreme;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class Send_request_id extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    Activity activity;
    String request_id;
    JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();

    public Send_request_id(Activity activity, String request_id) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.request_id = request_id;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {     
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        String url = "http://jstarfitness.com/service/saveuser.php";
        // String url = "http://jstarfitness.com/service/index.php";
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestid", request_id));
        String json_send = parser.makeHttpRequest(url, "post", param);
        JSONObject jobj = null;
        try {
            Log.e("Request-Id-Send", json_send);

            jobj = new JSONObject(json_send);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("Request-Id-Send", json_send);
            e.printStackTrace();
            String io = e.getMessage();

            Log.e("error", io);

        }
        return jobj;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("Id_Send", request_id);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: post your json return data and logcat.

Comment: Which line causes the NullPointerException?

Comment: Null pointer exception is shown at which line? Also Can you post JSON data

Comment: Post your Error from LogCat here

Comment: JSONParser is ur custom class rt? U can post ur custom class code.

Comment: 09-25 09:42:12.941: E/Buffer Error(24394): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
09-25 09:42:12.946: E/error(24394): End of input at character 0 of 
09-25 09:42:12.946: E/email(24394): katanu92@gmail.comnull
09-25 09:42:49.011: E/ViewRootImpl(24394): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
09-25 09:43:00.466: E/Buffer Error(24394): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
09-25 09:43:00.466: E/error(24394): End of input at character 0 of 
09-25 09:43:00.521: E/Id_Send(24394): 1465832530371742

Comment: this is my  error log its onpost method working properly Id_Send(24394): 1465832530371742  this is the log that i was declare in onpost method.

Comment: this error will come when any closing bracket or braises is remaining to close , so please check in webservice first and then parse it

Comment: thanks for reply guys Is this code is correct to send json data to a link????

Comment: You are probably getting a blank response. Its not null but the response is empty. So you are getting this error and not a Nullpointer exception. You please check your POST/GET variables.

Comment: if (method == "POST") {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
 this is post methode i use to send the data

Comment: If i use link that is configure with webservices it give this error but if i use blank link even then it gives the same error.... don't know where I'm stuck in this

Comment: @partik butani thanks there is a mistake in method.. thanx to suggest me .. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I got solution from the above comments  by make changes in the jsonparser class. changes in  the post method now data is sent to link successfull... thanks